# Branching to a c symbol from thumb inline assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, cortex-m, thumb

I'm on a Cortex-M0+ device (Thumb only) and I'm trying to dynamically generate some code in ram and then jump to it, like so:

```
uint16_t code_buf[18];
...
void jump() {
  register volatile uint32_t* PASET asm("r0") = &(PA->OUTSET.reg);
  register volatile uint32_t* PACLR asm("r1") = &(PA->OUTCLR.reg);
  register uint32_t set asm("r2") = startset;
  register uint32_t cl0 asm("r3") = clears[0];
  register uint32_t cl1 asm("r4") = clears[1];
  register uint32_t cl2 asm("r5") = clears[2];
  register uint32_t cl3 asm("r6") = clears[3];
  register uint32_t dl0 asm("r8") = delays[0];
  register uint32_t dl1 asm("r9") = delays[1];
  register uint32_t dl2 asm("r10") = delays[2];
  register uint32_t dl3 asm("r11") = delays[3];
  asm volatile (
    "bl code_buf\n"
     : [set]"+r" (set) : [PASET]"r" (PASET), [PACLR]"r" (PACLR), [cl0]"r" (cl0), [cl1]"r" (cl1), [cl2]"r" (cl2), [cl3]"r" (cl3), [dl0]"r" (dl0), [dl1]"r" (dl1), [dl2]"r" (dl2), [dl3]"r" (dl3) : "lr"
  );
}
```

The code in code_buf will use the arguments passed via registers (that's why I'm forcing specific registers).
This code compiles fine, but when I look at the disassembly the branch instruction has been changed to

```
     a14:   f004 ebb0   blx 0x5178
```

Which would try to switch the cpu to ARM mode and cause a HardFault. Is there a way to force the assembler to keep the branch as a simple bl?

Comment: the toolchain sees that as a non-thumb-function address so it is generating a blx to that address.  you need to either convince the toolchain that that label is a thumb function address.  Or what I tend to do in this situations other than just using real assembly is have this code be a function itself, declare it such that you can simply pass the address to code_buf as a parameter void hop ( uint16_t *);  in the function itself orr the incoming address (r0) with a 1, then use bx at the end with whatever register you have to spare, if any (which it doesnt look like you do...so

Comment: coming in to the function orr r0,#1, push r0,  do your other stuff at the end pop {pc}  lr will have been setup by the call to this asm code.

Comment: if you convince the toolchain that code_buf is a thumb function then when you try to access it as an array you may end up with unaligned accesses.  You can try making a pointer to a function, assining that functions address to code_buf and see if that does it.  in real asm (maybe inline) you could just define the array there .globl code_buf ;  code_buf: ; .thumb_func ; .globl code_fun ; code_fun:  .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  then use code_buf to fill it with data and code_fun as your bl address.

Comment: I tried using a function pointer like `void (*cb)(void) = (void (*)(void))code_buf;` but unfortunately the result was the same. The idea of putting the address in a register, orring it and jumping to it is really good although I'd have to use the last low register I have (r7) and hope the register allocator doesn't yell at me... However that's what I would do if I wasn't able to update my toolchain (see answer below)

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that the toolchain I was using (gcc 4.8) is buggy, and makes two errors: it interprets code_buf as an arm address, and produces a bogus `blx label` which isn't even legal on a cortex-m0+. I updated it to 6.3.1 and the inline asm was converted to a `bl label` as it was supposed to.

Comment: dont think the cortex-m0 was mainstream at that time, thumb was most definitely around it landed in the 2.x.x days and 3.x.x AFAIR was the first place we had it in gnu.  I dont agree that this was buggy as code_buf is not a thumb function label so the tools are free to think of it as whatever they want, thumb or not.  The or not produces what you got.  One could argue that it is a bug that they produced the bl instruction.  but either way it is good that by moving forward to a less old toolchain it worked.  8.x.x came out recently you should confirm versions after 4.x.x work as desired...

Comment: so you dont have to go through this again (for a while).

Comment: gcc7.3 is the current release, and has some *nice* improvements over 6.3: e.g. merging adjacent narrow stores into a single wider store (e.g. when writing a couple char or short struct members, it can use one word-sized `str` if alignment allows).  (gcc8.1 is out, but it's still very new).  Anyway, if you're going to take the time to switch compilers and rerun tests with a new toolchain, I'd suggest going all the way to 7.3 unless there's some specific reason *not* to.

Answer (score 1):

From section 4.1.1 of the [ARMv6-M Architecture Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0419d/DDI0419D_armv6m_arm.pdf):

> Thumb interworking is held as bit [0] of an *interworking address*.
>   Interworking addresses are used in the following instructions: `BX`,
>   `BLX`, or `POP` that loads the PC.
>
> ARMv6-M only supports the Thumb
>   instruction Execution state, therefore the value of address bit [0]
>   must be 1 in interworking instructions, otherwise a fault occurs. All
>   instructions ignore bit [0] and write bits [31:1]:’0’ when updating
>   the PC.

The target of your branch, `code_buf`, will be word-aligned (possibly double-word aligned) so bit 0 will be clear in its address.  The key is to ensure that bit 0 is set before you branch, and then even if the toolchain selects an interworking instruction you'll remain in thumb mode.

I don't have a development environment in front of me to test this, but I would suggest casting to a pointer-to-single-byte type and using pointer arithmetic to set bit 0:

```
uint8_t *thumb_target = ((uint8_t *)code_buf) + 1;
asm volatile (
  "bl thumb_target\n"
  : [set]"+r" (set) : [PASET]"r" (PASET), [PACLR]"r" (PACLR), [cl0]"r" (cl0), [cl1]"r" (cl1), [cl2]"r" (cl2), [cl3]"r" (cl3), [dl0]"r" (dl0), [dl1]"r" (dl1), [dl2]"r" (dl2), [dl3]"r" (dl3) : "lr"
);
```

**Edit:** The above doesn't work, as Peter Cordes points out, because a local variable can't be used in inline ASM in this context.  Not being well-versed in gcc's inline ASM, I won't attempt to fix it.

I have now had a chance to test the supplied code though, and gcc 7.2.1 with `-S -mtune=cortex-m0plus -fomit-frame-pointer` generates a `BL` not a `BLX`.

**Edit 2:** The documentation (section A6.7.14) suggests that only the register-target version of BLX is present in the ARMv6-M architecture (this is in common with the ARMv7 devices I'm most familiar with) and so it looks to me as if the fault is caused not by an attempt to switch to ARM mode but by an illegal instruction.  Is your compiler correctly configured?

Comment: Yes, that explains why `blx` crashes, but why does `bl code_buf` assemble to `blx` in the first place?  Is there not a separate `bl` Thumb opcode that doesn't do interworking and always stays in Thumb mode?

Comment: Try `bl code_buf+1`.  You definitely can't use a local var in an inline-asm template without making it an operand.  There is syntax for getting an immediate operand or something, and maybe a `%1` modifier to expand it in a way that could work, but `code_buf+1` should be much easier.  (And BTW, http://gcc.godbolt.org/ has ARM gcc installed, so you can check if it compiles, and see the asm output.)

Comment: My fault, lack of familiarity with GCC in this context (most of my ARM work is using the MDK-ARM compiler, and most of my GCC work is on desktop).  Edited the answer to leave the suggestion but make it clear that it doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your comments made me suspicious about my toolchain, and as it turns out while it was configured correctly it was producing a bogus output (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

IDK why your assembler would be changing `bl` into `blx`.  Mine doesn't, using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` 7.3.0 on Arch Linux.  `arm-none-eabi-as --version` shows Binutils 2.30.

```
unsigned short code_buf[18];
void jump() {
  asm("bl code_buf");
  asm("blx code_buf");  // still assembles to BL, not BLX
//  asm("blx jump");
//  asm("bl jump");
}
```

compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -nostdlib arm-bl.c -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb` (I made a linked executable with `-nostdlib` so I could see actual branch displacements, not placeholders).

Disassembling with `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d a.out` shows

```
00008000 <jump>:
    8000:       f010 f804       bl      1800c <__data_start>
    8004:       f010 f802       bl      1800c <__data_start>
    8008:       4770            bx      lr
    800a:       46c0            nop                     ; (mov r8, r8)
```

---

Your `f004 ebb0` may be a Thumb2 encoding for BLX.  I don't know why you're getting it.

The Thumb encoding for `bl` is documented in [section 5.19 of this ARM7TDMI ISA manual](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece222/ARM/ARM7-TDMI-manual-pt3.pdf#page=40) ("long branch with link"), but that manual doesn't mention a Thumb encoding for `blx` at all (because it's only Thumb, not Thumb 2).  The Thumb `bl` encoding stores the branch displacement right-shifted by 1 (i.e. without the low bit), and always stays in Thumb mode.

It's actually two separate instructions; one which puts the high 12 bits of the displacement into LR, and another which branches and updates LR to the return address.  (This 2-instruction hack allows Thumb1 to work without Thumb2 32-bit instructions).  Both instructions start with `f`, so your disassembly shows that you got something else; the first 16-bit chunk of `f004 ebb0` is the LR setup, but `ebb0` doesn't match any Thumb 1 instruction.

---

Possibly `asm("bl code_buf+1" : ...);` or `blx code_buf+1` could work, if the +1 convinces the assembler to treat it as a Thumb target.  But you might need to use asm to get a `.thumb_func` directive applied to `code_buf` somehow to keep your assembler happy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it turns out it was a buggy toolchain after all. Please see my answer below

Comment: you never want to use +1 in case the toolchain got it right you have then broken it, you want OR 1 so that if the toolchain gets it right or doesnt you get the correct value.  but sadly I think the gnu tools dont support that, better to just get the toolchain to do it right and not have to patch things up.